# Filefield with clearOnSubmit false is still cleared

Tags: javascript, extjs

I moved from `ExtJs 4.1` to `ExtJs 4.2`, because of terrible troubles with `filefield` component. The main trouble was that in `ExtJs 4.1` the filefield was cleared after each form submission. According to this [thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135109-File-upload-field-is-empty-by-re-submitting-of-the-form/page2), in `ExtJs 4.2` they solved this issue, however, I still face the very same problem in my application, in spite of the fact that I set `clearOnSubmit` to `false`. I even figured out what code causes the whole problems:

```
 Ext.define('Ext.form.field.FileButton', {
     ...
 createFileInput : function(isTemporary) {
    var me = this;
    //ATTENTION!
    //before me.el.createChild is called
    //me.fileInputEl contains initial filefield:
    //<input id="filefield-2144-button-fileInputEl" class=" x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="file_name" role="">
    me.fileInputEl = me.el.createChild({
        name: me.inputName,
        id: !isTemporary ? me.id + '-fileInputEl' : undefined,
        cls: me.inputCls,
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'file',
        size: 1
    });
    //ATTENTION!
    //now initial fielfield is gone, even though we have set clearOnSubmit to false
    me.fileInputEl.on('change', me.fireChange, me);  
  }
...
```

This library method is called at some moment, when the form is submitted to the server and destroyes the initial element:

```
 <input id="filefield-2144-button-fileInputEl" class=" x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="file_name" role="">
```

and replaces it with a new empty one:

```
<input name="file_name" id="ext-gen4414" class="x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1">
```

So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix this library bug.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it on 4.2.1. Its working fine.The filefield is not getting cleared after submit.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Upload a Photo',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            frame: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'photo',
                fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                labelWidth: 50,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'Select Photo...',
                clearOnSubmit: false
            }],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function() {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            url: 'photo-upload.php',
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                            success: function(fp, o) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```